Enabling a disabled button upon a notification being presented to the user
I am trying to enable a disabled button in iOS by using an observer when a notification is presented to the user. When an image is uploaded it is blurred, then 24 hours after the image is uploaded, a notification is presented. The interval is reduced for testing purposes. This is my first time using observers, background tasks, and notifications. The problem is that the unlock button is not being enabled when the notification is presented or when I adjust the UNNUserNotificationCenter.current() the unlock button is enabled immediately instead of when the notification is presented. I'm still learning so I know the syntax isn't perfect.
The observer in my super.viewDidLoad of ViewController
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name("EnableButtonNotification"), object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak self] _ in
self?.dayUnlockButton.isEnabled = true

AppDelegate:
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { granted, error in }
        BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: "com.TimeCapsule.removeBlur", using: nil) { task in
            self.handleAppRefresh(task: task as! BGAppRefreshTask)
        }
        return true
        
        func initializeBlurStates() {
           
            if UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "blurStates") == nil {
                let initialStates = [false, false, false, false]
                UserDefaults.standard.set(initialStates, forKey: "blurStates")
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    public func scheduleNotificationAndBackgroundTask() {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Time Capsule Ready"
        content.body = "Your Time Capsule is Ready!"
        content.sound = .default
        
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "Time Capsule Ready", content: content, trigger: trigger)
        
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
    
        let bgRequest = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: "com.TimeCapsule.removeBlur")
        bgRequest.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5) // Adjust as necessary
        do {
            try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(bgRequest)
        } catch {
            print("Could not schedule background task: \(error)")
        }
    }

            
            func handleAppRefresh(task: BGAppRefreshTask) {
                task.expirationHandler = {
                    task.setTaskCompleted(success: false)
                }
                
                // Perform data fetching or update the UI
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("RemoveBlurEffect"), object: nil)
                }
                
                task.setTaskCompleted(success: true)
            }
        }


...


extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
      func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) { completionHandler()
     }
     
     
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
      
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("EnableButtonNotification"), object: nil)
        completionHandler([.banner, .sound])
    }
}

I've tried adjusting the UNNUserNotificationCenter.current()add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil and i've tried adjusting the observer. Posting the UNNUserNotification enables the unlock button immediately instead of when the notification is presented.

Is the trigger for revealing the image the notification or simply that 24 hours has elapsed (which is the trigger for showing the notification) - I suspect that it is probably the latter, so you should just check the elapsed time when the app is opened rather than worrying about the notification
